# WMQ Uncommited msgs stuck in queue status data

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a queue for which the reader consumes messages under sycpoint and it ended abruptly. This caused 2 messages left in Uncommitted state. so the "msgage" property keeps increasing for the message and "uncom" property of queue remains same as 2, even though we restarted the consumer application and no long running UOW.

Anyway we can reset these properties without restarting MQ?

Answer (score 2):

Presuming your application is connecting in client mode (over TCP) I expect that although your application has gone away, from the queue manager's point of view it is still active.

When the network socket the application opened closes, then MQ should roll back the 2 messages so they're eligible for consumption by another application.

The network socket will close when the operating system eventually notices the remote end of the TCP connection is unresponsive - this triggers a 'connection reset by peer' type socket closure. It's the operating system the queue manager is running on which will do this, not the remote one.

Some operating systems can take hours to notice a duff socket in their default configuration. Look into 'TCP keepalive' settings on your operating system to tune how long this takes.

Comment: Thanks Tim.. TCP keepalive is set at 15 minutes in operating system.. Msg Age is now almost 5 days... :(